# How to authorize a user when he logs-in in react js?

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to authorize a user. I have made a login form. And after filling the form and clicking the login button the user should be authorized.

This is what I tried:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users', {}, {
  auth: {
    username: nameInForm,
    password: passwordInForm
}}).then(function(response) {
  alert("Authenticated");
}).catch(function(error) {
  alert("Error on Authentication");
});
```

Source: https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios

This is json data in my fake server:

```
"users": [
 {
  "id": 1,
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "admin"
 }
]
```

But even if I enter wrong username and password in the login form and I click the login button I always get the 'Authenticated' alert and a new user is created in the json fake server. I want to show the 'Error on Authentication' alert when I enter wrong username and password and show the 'Authenticated' alert when I enter the correct username and password.

Comment: Could you add here the code which is executed when calling `http://localhost:4000/users` ? If the result is always `"users": [ ... ]`, it seems that no error is sent so it will always succeed

Answer (score 1):

You need to handle response. For example, your response is for a successful login should be like that:

```
"users": [{
    "id": 1,
    "username": "admin",
    "password": "admin" // You shouldnt include password on the response for security concerns
}]
```

If your credentials are wrong your server should return like that:

```
"users": []
```

(also, including a success attribute will be great.)

Then you need to handle/differentiate this 2 different responses on Reactjs side. For example your code should be like that:

```
axios.post('http://localhost:4000/users', {}, {
   auth: {
   username: nameInForm,
   password: passwordInForm
}}).then(function(response) {
   if (response.data.users) {
      alert('Authenticated');
   } else {
      alert('Wrong Credentials');
   }
}).catch(function(error) {
   alert("Error on Authentication");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you kindly tell what is a success attribute and how to include it.